# Reading text file in Seleniumwebdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, notepad

I want to read values from a text file using selenium webdriver. I want to get third text from the text file. The text file is something like this.
1.Apple
2.Orange
3.Grape
I want to read the third option(Grape) and to display it. Please help

Comment: Have you tried anything ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to read the text file and **store data in a String** , then you can use some **regular expression** to get the third option.

```
String ps = ".*3.([A-Za-z]*)"; // regex
String s = "1.Apple 2.Orange 3.Grape"; // file data in a String object
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // returns value of s
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // returns result=  Grape

}
```

> Check regex here : https://regex101.com/r/cF9pB7/1

You can get some other values by changing the regulaar

Answer (score 0):

You do not need selenium to text file. Selenium is just a browser automation tool. You can use below code to read text file using Java.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can integrate it with your selenium code.

Comment: HI Mayur , Thank you. It works. But It displayed all the values. But in my case I just want to display only the third value mentioned above. Is that possible?

Comment: You may separate it by first space " " and iterate through string and later separate it by dot ".".

Comment: Hi Mayur, Actually I want to read it from Notepad as .txt file. From that .txt file I have  to select the third option.